# How do I get paginated data sorted by load date from the OSHA api detailed here?

Tags: api, labor

http://developer.dol.gov/health-and-safety/dol-osha-enforcement/#osha_accident

Without pagination it's useless and I'm forced to download and parse the entire CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `offset` filter

`https://data.dol.gov/get/accident/offset/0/limit/1` will give you the first result
`https://data.dol.gov/get/accident/offset/1/limit/1` will give you the second result
`https://data.dol.gov/get/accident/offset/2/limit/1` will give you the third result

...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you just need to implement `$top` and `$skip` in your api call:
http://developer.dol.gov/accessing-the-apis-using-http-requests/#pagination

Comment: Tried. Doesn't do anything :-/

Comment: can you share the url you used? just swap out your key for a fake one....

Comment: The fix is now in place.  We've updated our API documentation as well.  We're in the process of updating our dataset documentation as well as the feature is rolled out to all of our data sources.


  [1]: http://developer.dol.gov/accessing-the-apis-using-http-requests

Answer (score 1):

We have a patch sitting in our OCIO's office that will fix this issue.  Once it navigates that maze, pagination should work.