# what is the api call for getting all the inspection records, instead of getting default 200 records

Tags: api, labor

what is the api call for getting all the inspection records, or how to know the sequence numbers to be used for multiple calls to the same api, so that we can  get all the inspections records, instead of just getting default 200 records

https://data.dol.gov/get/inspection/format/xml/orderby/asc/columns/{activity_nr:open_date:site_address:site_city:site_state:insp_type:close_conf_date:close_case_date}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get paginated data sorted by load date from the OSHA api detailed here?](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6379/how-do-i-get-paginated-data-sorted-by-load-date-from-the-osha-api-detailed-here)

Answer (score 1):

We have a patch sitting in our OCIO's office that will fix the issue with pagination not working.  Once it navigates that maze, pagination beyond the first 200 records should work.

edit:  The fix is in place.  We've updated [our API documentation](http://developer.dol.gov/accessing-the-apis-using-http-requests) as well.  We're in the process of updating our dataset documentation as well as the feature is rolled out to all of our data sources.

Comment: `offset` seems to be working now. Is that not right?